# MUI how can I change the icon inside the TablePagination component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, material-ui

In my React project, I am using MUI component called `TablePagination`

`TablePagination` component is nested inside of the `Table` component like the picture below.

[image]

See how the dropdown button has a solid arrow pointing down.
How can I change this to a different SVG icon.

I want the new `TablePagination` to have an arrow icon from the below picture.

[image]

https://codesandbox.io/s/ijm5r?file=/demo.js

Here is the link to the sandbox for this example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a custom icon of the `Select` inside `TablePagination` like below:

```
<TablePagination
  SelectProps={{
    IconComponent: KeyboardArrowDownIcon,
  }}
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: is the "SelectProps" prop something that is universal to all other composite components ? In other words, can I always use "SelectProps" prop to override nested component like that ?